# WebSocket not working with HAProxy in tcp mode

Tags: java, spring, tcp, websocket, haproxy

Consider this `HAProxy` configuration here:

```
global
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 50s
    timeout server 50s

frontend fe_https_tomcat
    mode tcp
    bind *:443 ssl crt /path/cert.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    default_backend be_tomcat

backend be_tomcat
    mode tcp
    server localhost localhost:8081 check
```

The issue I have is that WebSocket do not seem to get through. My guess was that in tcp mode everything would pass through. Looks like it doesn't ... :-)

The server responds with an error `403` when the WebSocket connection is getting established.

Note that with the following http-mode setup, the WebSocket just works:

```
frontend fe_http_8080
    mode http
    bind *:8080
    default_backend be_tomcat_8080

backend be_tomcat_8080
    mode http
    server localhost localhost:8081 check
```

Note that I need tcp-mode to have http/2 working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not related to HAProxy at the end, but to the WebSocket setup in Spring.
This fixed it:

```
-registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler, "/ws");
+registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler, "/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
```